# Update record in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, sql-update

I use simple SQL to modyf ACC database conected to DataGridView via dataSet.xsc. Inserting works perfect, but updateing is fail (why?)
Table have 3 columns (2 strings and one boolean represented by Checkbox).

```html
UPDATE       Tabele
SET          We = True 'or False in another SQL
WHERE        (Name = ?) AND (Address = ?)
```

"We" is checkbox in table column, I try change by mouse in DataGridView. 
In code i used this line to modyf table:

```html
Private Sub Tabela_adresowDataGridView_CellContentClick(sender As Object, _
e As Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles _ 
Tabela_adresowDataGridView.CellContentClick
If e.ColumnIndex = 2 Then
Try
                With Tabela_adresowDataGridView
                    Me.Tabela_adresowBindingSource.EndEdit()
                    If .Item(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Selected = True Then
                        Me.Tabela_adresowTableAdapter.UpdateQuery_Checked(.Item(0, e.RowIndex).Value.ToString, _
                                                                          .Item(1, e.RowIndex).Value.ToString)
                    Else
                        Me.Tabela_adresowTableAdapter.UpdateQuery_Uncheck(.Item(0, e.RowIndex).Value.ToString, _
                                                                          .Item(1, e.RowIndex).Value.ToString)
                    End If
                    Tabela_adresowDataGridView.Update()
                    'Me.Validate()
                    'Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.Baza_adresowDataSet)
                    'Baza_adresowDataSet.AcceptChanges()
                End With
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If
```

Regardless of whether the inserted Primarykey or use one simple SQL with 3th parameter for a check state. Table is not modyfied. (?)

Comment: Can you create a local integer variable and assign the result of the Update to it then check to see what the value is. Update returns rows affected.

Answer (score 0):

Try to select your quert by you want and after put in your table:

```
    Dim SelectQuery As String = "Your Query"
    Dim WhereQuery As String = " WHERE (1=1)"

    ElseIf BOX_toDate.Text <> Nothing Then
        Name= WhereQuery & " AND TargetDate <= '" & Your value & "'"
    End If

        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

        con = FunctionConnection()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = SelectQuery & WhereQuery
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
```

Or like that: [How to search data in all tables in database using select query in vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30836364/how-to-search-data-in-all-tables-in-database-using-select-query-in-vb-net)

Comment: Im not using conection strings, but dataSet.xsc and I do not know why I should using Whare (1 = 1) in update... would you look on that one more time?

Comment: In where you can put all you need, like in your example "(Name = ?) AND (Address = ?)",

Comment: Et insert SQL in DataSet object I've: "INSERT INTO Tabele (Address, Name, We) VALUES (?, ?, ?)" and that works well. When I create update using wizard "(Name = ?) AND (Address = ?)" should be right.